# What does the listing directory on NYSE have?

Tags: equities, nyse

https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNGS:ACT

ACT is listed but does not have a current price. Does anybody know what are on listings_directory?

https://www.nyse.com/listings_directory/stock

How to find all the currently listed stocks?

Answer (score 1):

Despite having a 3 letter ticker symbol, ACT would be on NASDAQ, not on NYSE. However news stories say that its IPO, planned for earlier this year, has been postponed.

Here is a couple of news stories about the spinoff / renaming / IPO:

https://pages.genworth.com/about-enact

https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/introducing-enact-a-leading-private-mortgage-insurance-group-301297731.html

https://www.insurancebusinessmag.com/us/news/breaking-news/genworth-announces-ipo-rebrands-into-enact-holdings-254136.aspx

https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/genworth-financial-postpones-planned-ipo-of-enact-301290594.html

> Genworth Financial Postpones Planned IPO of Enact

https://techstockobserver.com/genworth-financial-inc-nyse-gnw-gains-after-releasing-enacts-monthly-report/

> CEO Tom McInerney said that Genworth’s Board of Directors determined
> that current market pricing for the anticipated IPO does not reflect
> Enact’s value following the recent trading volatility in the mortgage
> insurance (MI) sector. He added that the company postponed the IPO and
> will now focus on evaluating options as market conditions develop.